# Gulp: how to make generated file output to the same folder as source?

Tags: angularjs, minify, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-uglify

1) I've got an angular app setup with "[best practices for angular app structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub)". So each section's folder may have it's own *.scss file. Need to convert the *.scss to *.css, and output the *.css file in the same folder.

Been messing around with it in Gulp for a few hours but can't get the syntax right. It's giving me lots of different behaviors, none of which are desired.

Anyone know Gulp a little better?

2) Seperate Gulp question, uglify works to minify both CSS and JS files? Or is there a separate plugin to use for minifying CSS?

3) Is there a plugin to minify HTML files too? Not too familiar with what's available. Still trying to learn from an example, but they mangled all the different plugins together, and I don't need to use all of them. But as I pull them apart, I'm breaking a lot of things, so it's really time consuming to get things working. I can spend days on this, trying to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes I love Gulp more than grunt, and I have an example gist on github. You can check it here: https://gist.github.com/manar007/7ce4dd0bdd9b76edb2ea. It is for a large project, I think it will be helpful for you
2. Use `gulp-minify-css` and it mostly configured for CSS stuff
3. If you are building angular based application so the better way to configure templateCache and put all your HTML in to that and then concat it with your js file either embed like a different file 
   `gulp-angular-templatecache`

```
gulp.task('build-template-cache', function () {
  var stream = gulp.src('/app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(templateCache({
      module:'yourAngularModuleName'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir + '/js'));
  return stream;
});
```

And other examples you can find in above gist link.